# How do I return value (text) to the left of the max value (number) in col B, if Col A contains a keyword from a list?

Tags: excel

Column A in my table has text in it and I want to narrow my search to only the cells that contain a keyword from a list (e.g. cells that contain "keyword"). The value of each keyword is to the right (col B), and there are duplicate values. I want to return the text associated with the max value in col A. The furthest I've gotten was `=CELL("address",INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("keyword",A2:A5)),MAX(B2:B5),"false"),B2:B5,0)))`

This formula returns 20, which is the correct value, but the cell it returns is for A3 or the third row in the table (including headers), because it is the first time 20 appears.

| Words | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Wrong - keyword | 12 |
| Wrong | 20 |
| Right - keyword | 20 |
| Wrong | 20 |

Excel 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too bad you don't have Office 365 with the `FILTER` function, but you can try:

```
=INDEX(kwVal[Words],
      AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((kwVal[Values]= AGGREGATE(14,6,1/ISNUMBER(FIND("keyword",kwVal[Words]))*kwVal[Values],1))
           *ISNUMBER(FIND("keyword",kwVal[Words])))*ROW(kwVal),1)-ROW(kwVal[#Headers]))
```

Note that I used a **Table** with structured referencing, but you can change this to regular addressing if you prefer.

[image]

*In O365, you could use*

```
FILTER(kwVal,ISNUMBER(FIND("keyword",kwVal[Words]))),FILTER(INDEX(x,0,1),INDEX(x,0,2)=MAX(INDEX(x,0,2))))
```